# React + TypeScript usage of className prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript

What is the correct way to type and use the `className` prop in a custom component? I used to be able to do this:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component<MyProps, {}> {
  ...
}
```

and then use my component via:

```
<MyComponent className="my-class" />
```

Note that I would not define `className` in `MyProps`, though React was previously typed to support this usage.

Now, I am now seeing this type error:

```
Property 'className' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & 
IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<{}, ComponentState>> & Readonly<{ 
childr...'
```

What is the correct way to define / type my component that will allow me to use `className` when using my component?

Answer (score 96):

You can use the `HTMLAttributes` type, for example:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component<MyProps & React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, {}> {
    render() {
        return <div className={ this.props.className }>My Div</div>
    }
}
```

That way you can pass any of the properties that a html element might need.

If you only need the `className` property then you can do this:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component<MyProps & { className: string }, {}> {
    render() {
        return <div className={ this.props.className }>My Div</div>
    }
}
```

Or simply add it to your `MyProps` type.

Comment: Amazing, thanks. Perfect to also use the spread operator and pass any prop that is valid for a `<div>` element.

Answer (score 50):

For someone who are looking solution for functional components, as I was.

```
type Props = {
  className?: string
}

const MyComponent: React.FC<Props> = (props) => (
  <div className={props.className}>{props.children}</div>
)

export default MyComponent
```

or if you want to declare interface separately:

```
interface OnlyClassNameInterface extends React.FC<{className: string}> {}

const MyComponent: OnlyClassNameInterface = (props) => (
  <div className={props.className}>{props.children}</div>
)

export default MyComponent
```

and you can move interface to another file

```
import React from 'react'

type MixProps<P> = P & {className?: string}

export interface OnlyClassNameInterface<P = {}> extends React.FC<MixProps<P> {}
```

Comment: This answer gets to the point, specific and clean solution.

Comment: This is the correct solution for me. However, I had to extend the type on the functional component to be 
`Props & React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>`

Answer (score 7):

I myself always use the `HTMLProps` type by getting the `className` from it like this :

```
HTMLProps<HTMLElement>["className"];
```

It also works perfectly fine with `TailwindCSS` class names autocomplete functionality .

Comment: this should be the accepted answer

Comment: If the prop name is different than `className` (in the component) then this doesn't work (looses TS suggestions).

Comment: @Md.A.Apu The question is about correct way to type and use the ```className``` prop in a custom component so the prop name is always ```className``` .

Comment: @MehdiFaraji when the prop name is `className` then actually you only need `string` as type, I've tested this. Btw, do you know how to type it when prop name is something else?

Comment: @Md.A.Apu Yes you can extend the component interface with extra types like this :
`interface InputProps extends InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>`

Answer (score 2):

add a `react-native-class-name.polyfill.d.ts`

```
import 'react-native';
// polyfill className prop for react-native Components
declare module 'react-native' {
  interface TextProps {
    className?: string;
  }
  interface PressableProps {
    className?: string;
  }
  interface TextInputProps {
    className?: string;
  }

  interface ViewProps {
    className?: string;
  }
  interface InputAccessoryViewProps {
    className?: string;
  }

  interface ImagePropsBase {
    className?: string;
  }

  interface TouchableWithoutFeedbackProps {
    className?: string;
  }
  // others StyleProp<?> in node_modules/@types/react-native extends up show, should not define again.
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: God bless you for this, thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

Doing some search, I found that it is now suggested to use `React.PropsWithChildren`.

If you want to admit an attribute like classname, the code would be something like this

```
type AdditionalProps = {
    className?: string
}
type MyComponentProps = React.PropsWithChildren<AdditionalProps>;

export default function Text(props: MyComponentProps) {
    return (<p {...props}>
        {props.children}
    </p>)
}
```

This [logrocket article](https://blog.logrocket.com/using-react-children-prop-with-) is a good place to understand more about it.

Answer (score 1):

For react-native typescript with nativewind, use

```
/// <reference types="nativewind/types" />
```

See from the [documenation](https://www.nativewind.dev/getting-started/typescript)