# How can I use className on SVG imported as a component in Typescript React.FC

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svg, svg-react-loader

I have React, Typescript, svgr. Everything looks ok.

```
{
  test: /\.svg$/,
  use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
},
```

```
import Logo from 'assets/icons/logo.svg';
```

```
<Logo className={iconClassName} />;
```

TS doesn't like it.

> TS2322: Type '{ className: string; }' is not assignable to type
> 'IntrinsicAttributes'.   Property 'className' does not exist on type
> 'IntrinsicAttributes'.

What should I do about it?

Thanks!

PS Interesting! When I import `{ReactComponent as Logo}` - I don't have errors anymore.

Comment: refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44369706/react-typescript-usage-of-classname-prop

Comment: @Eric, it didn't work, but thanks

Answer (score 3):

I have created index.d.ts types file and have added following code

```
declare module "*.svg" {
  import React = require("react");
  const src: React.FC<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>;
  export default src;
}
```

This way you will also have access to other all props supported by svg tag

Note:- by default @svgr/webpack will try to export the React Component via default export i.e to import svg you have to import like `import Star from "./assets/star.svg"` and in this case above mentioned types were not working. so in webpack.config(next.config.js) i set the exportType option to named and so imports were `import { ReactComponent as Star} from "./assets/star.svg"` and the above typings were working.

```
 ....
{
      test: /\.svg$/i,
      issuer: { and: [/\.(js|ts)x?$/] },
      use: [
        {
          loader: '@svgr/webpack',
          options: { 
            exportType: 'named',
            ....
          },
        },
      ],
    }
....
```

Answer (score -1):

Think you cannot give className to components like that without using props. What I would suggest you to do is as follows:

```
import Logo from 'assets/icons/logo.svg';
<img src={Logo} className={iconClassName}/>
```

Comment: thanks, but when I use as an img, it breaks the project's css styles and other stuff. I have to use svg as a component.

Answer (score -1):

You can wrap the svg component and style it as a child of the parent element, hence you could do this

```
import Logo from 'assets/icons/logo.svg';

<div className={iconClassName}>
  <Logo />;
</div>
```

Then have a stylesheet somewhere targetting the svg child

```css
.iconClassName > :first-child {
  width: 400px;
  /* any other style you need */
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this code:

```
 <div className={iconClassName}>
  <img src="assets/icons/logo.svg"/>
 </div>
```

Comment: While this piece of code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users refer to and eventually apply this knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Comment: thanks, but when I use as an img, it breaks the project's css styles and other stuff. I have to use svg as a component.